# How to make a component input file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, input

I need to create a simple component in angularJS that read an input field in a view.
I tried to use the several examples that there is here and in others sites.
But it is not working.
I want to do it with .component and not with directive in easy way but I don't know how to do it.

inside  uploadFile function $scope.file always appear "undefined". Why So ?

**The core of my question is How i will get file of the view inside my component?**

Below my code..

```js
'use strict';

angular.
    module('fileUpload').
 component('fileUpload',{  
  templateUrl: 'app/fileUpload/fileUpload.view.html',
  controller: ['Restangular', function($scope){
       var self = this;
       var fileIcon = [];
       self.uploadFile = uploadFile;
         self.sendFile = sendFile;
          
   self.$onInit= function(){
    console.log("object fileUpload created");
   }              

      function uploadFile(){       
       fileIcon = $scope.file;
          console.log('file is ' );
          console.dir(file);
      } 

   function sendFile(){
    console.log('inside send File....');
    console.log('content fileIcon....'+ fileIcone);
     var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append('file', fileIcon);
          console.log("fd ...:" + fd);
         
   }          
  }]
 });
```

```html
<div>   
 <input type="file" id="myFile" file-model="file"/> 
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.sendFile()">Send</button>     
</div>
```

In advanced Thank you so much.

Comment: try this http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngFileReader

Comment: Where does the `file-upload` directive that you've used in the input come from?

Comment: I have an other component x. Inside view him  i call <file-Upload></file-Upload>. Over there the file-upload appears. But i can not to access him file-model...

Comment: I'am trying any way....

Comment: Component: angular.
 module('fileUpload').
 component('fileUpload',{  
  templateUrl: 'app/fileUpload/fileUpload.view.html',
  controller: [function(){
       var self = this;              
       self.fileIcon = {};
  
   self.$onInit= function(){
    console.log("object fileUpload created");
   }          

   self.fileIcon = function(){
    alert("In...selecting a file...");
   }
 
  }]
 });

Comment: view: 
<div> 
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="$ctrl.fileIcon()" />    
</div>

Comment: However, the following error to appears "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ctrl is not defined"

Comment: Anybody can help me?